# How to access elements in a json file with python

Tags: python, json

I'm quite new in python and json, so I have many times a problem identifying the right structure of spotify json files in order to access specific items.
Well, with python I started also dealing with json files and so I try to use python for this matter.
I always have to try different paths to access e.g. a track name until I come to the right one, 
i.e. "trial and error" method.

What I want is having a **clear view of the json structure beforehand** so I know exactly which path to use in order to access a specific element.

**Here is an example file:**

```
    {
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/<user>/playlists/0WakN.../tracks?offset=0&limit=100&market=ES",
  "items" : [ {
    "added_at" : "2016-10-01T20:30:03Z",
    "added_by" : {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/<user>"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/<user>",
      "id" : "<user>",
      "type" : "user",
      "uri" : "spotify:user:<user>"
    },
    "is_local" : false,
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/61Jlgdh66274FjDeqSosCU"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/61Jlgdh66274FjDeqSosCU",
        "id" : "61Jlgdh66274FjDeqSosCU",
        "images" : [ {
          "height" : 640,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/8da566952192f2c07b0557ce0b18f730c84ba1a3",
          "width" : 640
        }, {
          "height" : 300,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/904046908fb220aacf4308cd8ae055cb88d6a6af",
          "width" : 300
        }, {
          "height" : 64,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/a08529c336b33937f0cbb678ffbb15e73f7f15fa",
          "width" : 64
        } ],
        "name" : "20 AÃ±os La Historia (En Vivo)",
        "type" : "album",
        "uri" : "spotify:album:61Jlgdh66274FjDeqSosCU"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2SYIF2tMAgLcjtTTeCfjg3"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2SYIF2tMAgLcjtTTeCfjg3",
        "id" : "2SYIF2tMAgLcjtTTeCfjg3",
        "name" : "Porfi Baloa",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:2SYIF2tMAgLcjtTTeCfjg3"
      } ],
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 207880,
      "explicit" : false,
      "external_ids" : {
        "isrc" : "QMHUY1559454"
      },
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/5VVIsLFq7c6CT0vsr9J3Py"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5VVIsLFq7c6CT0vsr9J3Py",
      "id" : "5VVIsLFq7c6CT0vsr9J3Py",
      "is_playable" : true,
      "linked_from" : {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/5Cv09ZTlg3La9nlJejGlX7"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5Cv09ZTlg3La9nlJejGlX7",
        "id" : "5Cv09ZTlg3La9nlJejGlX7",
        "type" : "track",
        "uri" : "spotify:track:5Cv09ZTlg3La9nlJejGlX7"
      },
      "name" : "Dame una Oportunidad - En Vivo",
      "popularity" : 14,
      "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/8e3f576a0cf9aee6a0c52c2ae3b1c73bf9de2c7f",
      "track_number" : 2,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "spotify:track:5VVIsLFq7c6CT0vsr9J3Py"
    }
  }, {
    "added_at" : "2016-10-04T20:03:20Z",
    "added_by" : {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/<user>"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/<user>",
      "id" : "<user>",
      "type" : "user",
      "uri" : "spotify:user:<user>"
    },
    "is_local" : false,
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/0GxUdSpTj1PeJlqq0knC5I"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0GxUdSpTj1PeJlqq0knC5I",
        "id" : "0GxUdSpTj1PeJlqq0knC5I",
        "images" : [ {
          "height" : 636,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/ad15a75e71dce1a0c8e04f3d8a919a5185bcfa94",
          "width" : 640
        }, {
          "height" : 298,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/9ceb0585e856a11002ca60388e1e8821316f5f2a",
          "width" : 300
        }, {
          "height" : 64,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/08822c412704203f7fb80f9ba3bab3147180848f",
          "width" : 64
        } ],
        "name" : "Contraste En Salsa",
        "type" : "album",
        "uri" : "spotify:album:0GxUdSpTj1PeJlqq0knC5I"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/27vNK840zYq6IfDijHPsv1"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/27vNK840zYq6IfDijHPsv1",
        "id" : "27vNK840zYq6IfDijHPsv1",
        "name" : "Gilberto Santa Rosa",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:27vNK840zYq6IfDijHPsv1"
      } ],
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 266786,
      "explicit" : false,
      "external_ids" : {
        "isrc" : "USSD10704531"
      },
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/5YfqVqJwjxiyhxvofbCnHp"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5YfqVqJwjxiyhxvofbCnHp",
      "id" : "5YfqVqJwjxiyhxvofbCnHp",
      "is_playable" : true,
      "name" : "Conteo Regresivo - Salsa Version",
      "popularity" : 56,
      "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/cea9a58f7b87267974d8f8261eb4670be3129777",
      "track_number" : 1,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "spotify:track:5YfqVqJwjxiyhxvofbCnHp"
    }
  }, {
    "added_at" : "2016-10-05T19:11:57Z",
    "added_by" : {
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/<user>"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/<user>",
      "id" : "<user>",
      "type" : "user",
      "uri" : "spotify:user:<user>"
    },
    "is_local" : false,
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/70XO7jxoVIV9p9IFyjXGvJ"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/70XO7jxoVIV9p9IFyjXGvJ",
        "id" : "70XO7jxoVIV9p9IFyjXGvJ",
        "images" : [ {
          "height" : 640,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/5314594bebbeb59cb89b0779e03d9cdf0f84fe73",
          "width" : 640
        }, {
          "height" : 300,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/888f3bcd4f7644655ec966b2c80bb0d591e5b17f",
          "width" : 300
        }, {
          "height" : 64,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/7e9afbb36171a99f980ea7b71142a5e7fec68f47",
          "width" : 64
        } ],
        "name" : "Sigo Siendo Yo",
        "type" : "album",
        "uri" : "spotify:album:70XO7jxoVIV9p9IFyjXGvJ"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4wLXwxDeWQ8mtUIRPxGiD6"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4wLXwxDeWQ8mtUIRPxGiD6",
        "id" : "4wLXwxDeWQ8mtUIRPxGiD6",
        "name" : "Marc Anthony",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:4wLXwxDeWQ8mtUIRPxGiD6"
      } ],
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 289293,
      "explicit" : false,
      "external_ids" : {
        "isrc" : "NLB630400179"
      },
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/4pUmQqaZklcCOB3rFdWc7g"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4pUmQqaZklcCOB3rFdWc7g",
      "id" : "4pUmQqaZklcCOB3rFdWc7g",
      "is_playable" : true,
      "name" : "ValiÃ³ la Pena - Salsa Version",
      "popularity" : 65,
      "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/50e896ef946dc1585153b380a9f63d02f8244553",
      "track_number" : 9,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "spotify:track:4pUmQqaZklcCOB3rFdWc7g"
    }
  } ],
  "limit" : 100,
  "next" : null,
  "offset" : 0,
  "previous" : null,
  "total" : 3
}
```

To access e.g. the artist name of a track from this playlist I use:

```
data = json.load(playlist_file)
artist_name = data["items"][x]["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
```

But I "lost" quite a time to come to this path.
Is there some method to see clearly the **structure of a long json** file?

I thought perhaps pretty printing just the keys with all of the brackets could make the whole more clear(because many of the values are very long)?

Thanks

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20json?mode=all

Comment: Oh yes, good links to get educated in this area! Thanks a lot, Shivkumar

Answer (score 0):

If pretty printing is your objective,

```
f = open('/path/to/spotify.json', 'r')
loaded = json.load(f)
print json.dumps(loaded, indent=4)
```

**Update:**

To get all the possible paths within a json

```
import ijson

f = open('spotify.json', 'r')
parser = ijson.parse(f)
paths = sorted(set(prefix for prefix, event, value in parser if prefix))

for path in paths:
    print path
```

Sample Outcome:

```
    href
    items
    items.item
    items.item.added_at
    items.item.added_by
    items.item.added_by.external_urls
    items.item.added_by.external_urls.spotify
    items.item.added_by.href
    items.item.added_by.id
    ....
```

Here *item* denotes presence of array

Comment: thanks for the answer! Nevertheless my real object is to recognize the structure of the json file.

Comment: What do you expect as structure here? The Hierarchy of keys? Could you please update the question with specifics!

Comment: Well, if I want to know the name of the artist of a track in a playlist like the one above, I'd like to get to know as fast as possible which path I have to use, in order to access this desired information. After many tries I now know for this case it is the path >artist_name = data["items"][x]["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]<. The key name exists also in other paths but I want to access the right one without trying a lot. I further want to know e.g. the albums name, the track name, the spotify ID of the artist, the album id and so on...

Comment: ...If the values are very long like here then the structure isn't that clear any more. So if I could print the whole with say the first 5 characters of each value, it could probably help also.

Comment: I ve updated the answer to fetch the key paths within a json.

Comment: Exactly! That's very usefull to me. It's quite about what I was looking for... Thanks a lot!